# Dictionary/list comprehension to assign new dict values from lists to predefined keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have 2 lists containing strings (they could also be changed to sets instead, if that makes a difference here):

```
names = ['abc' , 'xyz' , 'foo']
ids = ['1234' , '5678' , '9101']
```

The number of items in the lists will vary, but each list will always have the exact same number of items and fewer than a dozen or so. I need to create a dictionary `output` from those lists and assign the list items as values in a list of dicts structured like this:

```
[{'name' : 'abc', 'id' : '1234'},
 {'name' : 'xyz', 'id' : '5678'},
 {'name' : 'foo', 'id' : '9101'}]
```

It's also important for this function that the values match up consistently, as the lists are generated in a specific order and need to remain so. Meaning, `'name' : 'abc'` should always be on the same line as `'id' : '1234'`, given the above source lists. The first value in one list should be paired with the first in the other, the second with the second, and so on.

I've tried tons of things and can't even get close enough to provide a useful example of "what I've tried." I'm just fundamentally not understanding something about the way comprehensions work, I think.

**edit - this is marked as a duplicate and the dupe seems to address the same need, although the text and the title of it focusing on "json format" instead of "list of dicts" or something meant I wouldn't have found it. Hopefully my question leads some people searching with slightly different terms to the answer, thank you.

Comment: Which version of python?

Comment: sorry, this would be in 3.6

Comment: Problem: your object in the "structured like this:" block is not a valid object. the outer curly brackets imply it is a set or a dict; but sets can't contain dictionaries, and a dictionary can only contain key-value pairs, not individual values. Perhaps what you really want is a list of dicts.

Comment: that's probably the case, yes, sorry, adjusting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` + list/dict comprehensions:

```
names = ['abc' , 'xyz' , 'foo']
ids = ['1234' , '5678' , '9101']

res = [{"name": n, "id": i} for n, i in zip(names, ids)]
```

Comment: Right, I missed that part of the OP. Seems I got lucky)

Comment: By my interpretation of the requirements, it's OK if the key-value pairs in each dict are in whatever order, as long as "abc" is in the same dict as "1234", and "xyz" with "5678", etc; and the dict containing "abc" precedes the one containing "xyz", etc. Both of those conditions hold for this solution.

Comment: I guess they could be on the same vertical line...

Comment: Kevin's comment is accurate, I actually don't even care what order the dicts themselves are in as long as the correct name ends up with the correct id. I've tested ~20 times and it seems very consistently so. Thank you!